# Increasing and subadditivity implies a convex inverse exists

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If $f$ is an increasing and subadditive function on the nonnegative reals such that $f(0) =0$, then $f$ has an inverse and furthermore $f^{-1}$ is convex.

How would I go about proving existence? My intuition is once existence has been proved I can use the fact that subadditivity implies concave and so the inverse must be convex. Is this correct?

Comment: Subadditive and increasing does *not* imply concave, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/q/35669/116247.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For existence, you note that any strictly monotone function has an inverse function from its range to its domain. In this case, you know that the infimum of its range is $0.$ You do *not* know that the range is all of $[0, \infty]$ The rest of your argument is fine.